# Http modules integrated into IIS 7 processing pipeline

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, authentication, iis-7

Q1 -IIS7 by default automatically registers *FormsAuthenticationModule* ( which is defined in root *web.config* file ), but does the term “*Http module being integrated into IIS 7  processing pipeline refers*” only to cases where this registered module is also configured to work with non-Asp.Net applications?

In my opinion if module is not configured to work with non-Asp.Net applications, even if it is automatically registered by IIS 7, then we can’t really claim that it is integrated into IIS 7’s processing pipeline?!

Q2

A) IIS7 automatically registers some of the modules defined in root *web.config* file. 
If we configure ( via IIS7 manager )  *UrlAuthorizationModule* ( which is defined in root *web.config* and which IIS 7 registers by default ) to be used with non-Asp.Net apps also, then IIS7 puts the following entry into application’s root *web.config* file:

```
  <modules>
        <remove name="UrlAuthorization" />
        <add name="UrlAuthorization" type="System.Web.Security.UrlAuthorizationModule" preCondition="" />
```

But why did IIS 7 also include `<remove name="UrlAuthorization" />` element?

B) I assume if we then change our mind and decide to use this module only with Asp.Net applications, we can safely remove the following element:

```
<add name="UrlAuthorization" type="System.Web.Security.UrlAuthorizationModule" preCondition="" />
```

from application’s root *web.config* file, since now our application can use *UrlAuthorizationModule* defined in root web.config?!

Q3

I realize IIS7 by default registers *FormsAuthenticationModule* defined in root *web.config* file, but assume we register another *FormsAuthenticationModule* in *web.config* contained in a root directory of some web application.

- I assume when request for web page is received, two instances of *FormsAuthenticationModule* will be executed for that request?

thanx

**EDIT:**

A1.

> "integrated" vs "classic" processing pipelines is a property on the application pool. It is correct that modules can be set to run only in "integrated" pipelines.

My question was referring to IIS 7 in integrated mode. Namely, my book uses the term “*Http module being integrated into IIS 7  processing pipeline refers*” to describe a situation where custom Http handler has been registered with IIS 7 (running in integrated mode). But it doesn’t say whether the term refers to situation when this registered handler is configured to work with non-asp.net applications also or do we also use this term when registered Http handler is configured to only work with Asp.Net applications?

> A2. B. Yes, you can remove the "remove" as well as the "add" lines. This is what the GUI will do if you change it back to inherit the settings.

But in my case IIS 7 doesn’t remove

```
<add name="UrlAuthorization" type="System.Web.Security.UrlAuthorizationModule" preCondition="" />
```

from application’s root *web.config* file,,it just changes  the value of *preCondition* attribute back to   *"managedHandler"*

> A3. I think you'll get an error if you try to add 2 modules that have the same "name" attribute. If you really want it in there twice then change the "name" of the 2nd one.

I apologize, I should be more specific, but my question was referring to a situation where two modules would have different names.

So in that case there will be two instances of *FormsAuthenticationModule* running?

thanx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just noticed that you are using Stackoverflow. Please check my latest answers at iis.net.

http://forums.iis.net/t/1157580.aspx

An important thing is that applicationHost.config and root web.config actually have different meaning still, so don't be confused if an item appears in both files. That actually has different meanings.

Answer (score 1):

A1.  "integrated" vs "classic" processing pipelines is a property on the application pool.  It is correct that modules can be set to run only in "integrated" pipelines.

A2.
A.  In order to change the "preCondition" attribute, it had to remove the first version and add it again.

A2. B.  Yes, you can remove the "remove" as well as the "add" lines.  This is what the GUI will do if you change it back to inherit the settings.

A3. I think you'll get an error if you try to add 2 modules that have the same "name" attribute.  If you really want it in there twice then change the "name" of the 2nd one.

Comment: David, you may also check my answers at iis.net forums, as this is really a complicated case to study. :)